# Pomodoro Timer: Variable value goes to 'NaN'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a Pomodoro clock like http://codepen.io/GeoffStorbeck/full/RPbGxZ/. The value of seconds goes to NaN randomly and then returns to normal after starting 'break'.

```
$('#circle a').click(function() {
  var timer = $('.time > span').html();
  timer = timer.split(':'); 
  var minutes = timer[0];    //Value of minutes
  var seconds = timer[1];    //Value of seconds

  var settimer = setInterval(function() {
    seconds -= 1;
    console.log(seconds);
    if (seconds < 0 && minutes != 0) {
      minutes -= 1;
      minutes = String(minutes);
      seconds = 59;
    } else if (seconds < 10 && seconds.length != 2)
      seconds = '0' + seconds; 
    if (minutes < 10 && minutes.length < 2) 
      minutes = '0' + minutes;

    $('.time > span').html(minutes + ':' + seconds);

    //Start break when session is completed
    if (minutes == 0 && seconds == 0) {
      $('.upper').find('h1').text('BREAK');
      var time = $('#break').find('span').text();
      $('.time > span').html('0' + time + ':00');
      $('#circle a').trigger("click");  //Start timer for break
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

Here's the link to the codepen
http://codepen.io/ibrahimjarif/pen/wMKJWN

How do I fix the NaN issue?
And is there any better way to implement this?

Comment: A few tips: don’t use `parseInt` without the second argument (`10`). Use `.toString()` instead of `String(`…`)`. Work with numbers the _whole_ time: `var minutes = Number(timer[0]), seconds = Number(timer[1]);`, only append the leading `0` or convert to string _when writing the new timer_ with the `.html` function.

Comment: @Xufox Thanks for the input. Fixed the code.

Comment: @Xufox Should I delete the question as I have solved the issue? I'm a newbie. So please suggest.

Comment: @Ibrahim The purpose of SO is to have a future reference of the questions that have been posted by the comunity to be usefull to resolve developer problems, so you have to let your question exists for future reference.

Comment: @Xufox wouldn't it be better to convert your comment into an answer, since it answered the question?

Comment: @xophos Xufox's comment didn't fix the code. It was an improvement to the existing code.

Comment: @xophos You can always post an answer yourself and mark it as community wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `$('#circle a').trigger("click");  //Start timer for break` recursively calls the function that was executing originally. This call starts a new timer while the original one was in progress.

The `seconds` value for the original timer went to `NaN` when the new timer was executing. There were two values for `second` due to two timers. The  value of `seconds` in the original timer caused the unexplained appearance of `NaN`.

NOTE: Both the timers were running simultaneously all the time.

The simplest fix was to stop the current timer before starting a new one.

Here's the updated code

```
 $('#circle a').click(function() {
  var timer = $('.time > span').html().split(':');;
  var minutes = Number(timer[0]),
    seconds = Number(timer[1]);

  var settimer = setInterval(function() {
    seconds -= 1;
    if (seconds < 0 && minutes != 0) {
      minutes -= 1;
      seconds = 59;
    } else if (seconds < 10 && seconds.length != 2)
      seconds = '0' + seconds;
    if (minutes < 10 && minutes.toString().length < 2)
      minutes = '0' + minutes;

    $('.time > span').html(minutes + ':' + seconds);

    if (minutes == 0 && seconds == 0) {
      clearInterval(settimer);    //Stop the current timer
      var upper_text = $('.upper').find('h1');
      var time;
      if (upper_text.text() == 'BREAK') {
        upper_text.text('Session');
        time = $('#session').find('span').text();
      } else {
        upper_text.text('BREAK');
        time = $('#break').find('span').text();
      }
      $('.time > span').html(time + ':00');
      $('#circle a').trigger("click");    //Start new timer
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```