# make something happen every 1 second?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop, timer

I am currently challenging myself by creating a Pomodoro timer. I'm having trouble making the timer count down automatically... So far I am thinking of using a for loop although it does not count down 59..58..57.. on the screen. My question is can I make it slower...

I currently have this if/else statement that will allow everything to go from 59 - 0 then reset to 59 again.

```
if (s >=0 && s < 10 ) {
    $("#second").html("0"+s);
    s--
} else if ( s <= 0) {
    s = 59;
} else {
    $("#second").html(s); 
    s--
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pomodoro Timer: Variable value goes to 'NaN'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34340941/pomodoro-timer-variable-value-goes-to-nan)

Comment: look into `setInterval`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function runTimer() {
  let count = 59

  setInterval(() => {
    console.log(count)
    count--
    if (count < 1) count = 59
  }, 1000)
}

runTimer()
```